# How to put data produced by my terminal into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am a beginner to programming in general, and my situation is as follows.

I am doing a computation using software (polymake) that I'm running interactively with my terminal, and my computation output some numeric data that looks like this:

```
facet 1 contains vertices:
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 -8566355578160561/9007199254740992 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 8566355578160561/9007199254740992 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1323574716436937/2251799813685248 -7286977229400801/9007199254740992 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 -4044484486813853/18014398509481984 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 4044484486813853/18014398509481984 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 -3272056622340821/9007199254740992 -4252622667048423/36028797018963968 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 -6880887921216781/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 1000927696824871/2251799813685248 -6629910960894707/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 -8566355578160561/9007199254740992 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 8566355578160561/9007199254740992 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1323574716436937/2251799813685248 -7286977229400801/9007199254740992 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
1 -4044484486813853/18014398509481984 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
1 4044484486813853/18014398509481984 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
1 -3272056622340821/9007199254740992 -4252622667048423/36028797018963968 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0
1 0 -6880887921216781/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
1 1000927696824871/2251799813685248 -6629910960894707/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2

facet 2 contains vertices:
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 -1323574716436937/2251799813685248 -7286977229400801/9007199254740992 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 -8566355578160561/9007199254740992 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 8566355578160561/9007199254740992 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1323574716436937/2251799813685248 -7286977229400801/9007199254740992 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 -4044484486813853/18014398509481984 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 4044484486813853/18014398509481984 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
1 0 -6880887921216781/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 1000927696824871/2251799813685248 -6629910960894707/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 -1323574716436937/2251799813685248 -7286977229400801/9007199254740992 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 -8566355578160561/9007199254740992 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 8566355578160561/9007199254740992 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1323574716436937/2251799813685248 -7286977229400801/9007199254740992 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
1 -4044484486813853/18014398509481984 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
1 4044484486813853/18014398509481984 5566755204060609/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0
1 0 -6880887921216781/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
1 1000927696824871/2251799813685248 -6629910960894707/18014398509481984 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
```

I need to use this data to do computations, which I am doing using Python.

In order for me to run my algorithm on the data, I need to first organize it into numpy arrays as follows:

```py
F_2 = np.array([
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [-1323574716436937/2251799813685248,-7286977229400801/9007199254740992,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [-8566355578160561/9007199254740992,5566755204060609/18014398509481984,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [8566355578160561/9007199254740992,5566755204060609/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1323574716436937/2251799813685248,-7286977229400801/9007199254740992,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [-4044484486813853/18014398509481984,5566755204060609/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [4044484486813853/18014398509481984,5566755204060609/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
    [0,-6880887921216781/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
    [1000927696824871/2251799813685248,-6629910960894707/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [-1323574716436937/2251799813685248,-7286977229400801/9007199254740992,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [-8566355578160561/9007199254740992,5566755204060609/18014398509481984,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [8566355578160561/9007199254740992,5566755204060609/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1323574716436937/2251799813685248,-7286977229400801/9007199254740992,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0],
    [-4044484486813853/18014398509481984,5566755204060609/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],
    [4044484486813853/18014398509481984,5566755204060609/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0],
    [0,-6880887921216781/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],
    [1000927696824871/2251799813685248,-6629910960894707/18014398509481984,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2]
])
```

This is extremely tedious to do by hand, since I have to place the data manually into a 2D numpy array. This involves having to place commas separating the numbers, and putting the sequences of numbers on each line between square brackets to form the rows of the 2D array etc.

I am wondering if there is a way I can do this much faster with programming commands (especially since I have to do this many times)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: so in both answers below you need to save a file - which is the way i would do it too. but if you don't want to save the data to a file you might want to look into sys.argv in your python code to be able to stay use it from the terminal

Comment: Could you please replace the images with the actual text version of them? It will be easier for us to copy and test on our side.

Comment: How are you running your program? Do you just open a terminal and run it?

Comment: yes I opened terminal and ran it.  @accdias I am very new to this, not sure how to do that to be honest.

Comment: @trynalearn, edit your post and then just copy and paste the text from the terminal into it.

Comment: Take a look at [pypolymake](https://pypi.org/project/pypolymake/).

Comment: @Frank Musterman - it's no need to save to a file. The output comes from somewhere, I assume a method. Instead of saving to a file, it can be as such passed on as an input. I am not familiar with the code that produces the given output, but surely there are options other than saving to a file

Answer (score 0):

use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('yourContent', delimiter=r' ')
```

Comment: This is far from being a solution for the problem described on OP.

Comment: Is pandas clever enough to skip the `facet x contains vertices` lines?

Answer (score 0):

You could copy-paste your data into a text file and then use [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), e.g.:

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.genfromtxt(filepath)
```

more info no how to use it in the linked documentation.

---

An even more efficient approach would be to collect the output of your script.
One way of doing this in Python is by running the output-producing script via [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) functionalities (e.g. `subprocess.run()`).

Comment: I don't believe that will solve the problem described on OP. I guess he needs something to be used as `pipe` filter instead.